# Axios not setup properly in Vuex Store - Vue.js & Electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, axios, electron-vue

I'm using [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) to build a simple desktop app.

I used all of the standard configurations at the beginning (including adding axios), but I'm currently having an issue getting

Part of my file structure is this:
[image]

---

My main file looks like this: (`src/renderer/main`):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from  './axios'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

if (!process.env.IS_WEB) Vue.use(require('vue-electron'))
Vue.axios = Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  components: { App },
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app')
```

---

And my axios file looks like this (`src/renderer/axios`)

```
import axios from 'axios'

const ax = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'localhost:5000'
})

export default ax
```

---

And using it in a store:

```
import axios from '@/axios'

// state, & mutations code...

const actions = {
  async testAction({ commit }) {
    const { data } = await axios.$post('/testAction', {id: -1})
    console.log(data)
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutation,
  actions
}
```

---

I keep getting the error:
**`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.$post is not a function`**

Any insight into what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Use `axios.post`

Comment: silly error, thank you!